# check if localStorage value has changed and add them to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an event listener that will pick up when the value of a localstorage item changes,
however I'm not sure how I can then push the value of the item that's changed into my `modulesCompleted state`

Ideally I want an array that will tell me which value has changed and set it to state

so I would end up with `state.modulesCompleted = ['structureAndDetails', 'hydraulics']`

If I try to use setModulesCompleted in the callback it throws an error that it can't update

**training.js**

```
 {typeof window !== 'undefined' && localStorage.setItem(topic.slug, topic.progress)}
document.dispatchEvent(new Event('storageChanged'));
```

**sidebar.js**

```
const Sidebar = () => {
 const [modulesCompleted, setModuleCompleted] = useState([])
  const storageHandler = useCallback(() => {
    const structureAndDetails = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? Number(localStorage.getItem('structure-and-details')) : null
    const hydraulics = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? Number(localStorage.getItem('hydraulics')) : null

    console.log('hydraulics',hydraulics)
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("storageChanged", storageHandler, false);

    // Don't forget to remove event listener on component unmount
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("storageChanged", storageHandler);
    };
  }, [storageHandler]);

  ...
}
```